# Excel: I want to find cells that have duplicate text WITHIN the cell itself

Tags: excel, duplicates

I know how to find duplicate cells using conditional formatting, but that's comparing text between 2 or more cells.

I need to bring back cells that have duplicate text within each of the cells.

Example:

```
-allstar company allstar co
-best products inc
-chemical corporation chemical corp
-dumont petro
-EPT corp E P T corp
```

Here are 5 cells with text.  Cells 1,3, and 5 have duplicate text and should be brought back, or highlighted.

I don't know VBA so if it can be avoided, that would be best.

Thanks all

Comment: Are we safe to assume that duplicates will be delimited by a space? In other words,`allstar company all star company` should only take out "company", right?  So in your example, the last one, we'd know it's a duplicate because of `corp`, *not* `EPT`, since that only appears once.  Can you see where an issue may come up? Would `microsoft corp apple corp` be highlighted, since "corp" is in there twice?  Perhaps you have a "main list" of these companies somewhere that you can compare to?

Comment: Or if space is a reasonable assumption to split, you could leverage text to columns and some combination of find functions maybe?  It wouldn't be easy to do dynamically.

Comment: yes, a space in between

Answer (score 0):

So assuming that you're looking for whole words, we can separate them by space.  I know you want to avoid VBA, but that is the only way I know how to do this in any sort of automated fashion.  So, if you insert a module to your spreadsheet, you can use this function I wrote here, and then call it from your cell.

```
Option Explicit
Public Function DuplicateWordCheck(text As String) As Boolean
    Dim textArray As Variant, i As Integer, j As Integer
    DuplicateWordCheck = False
    textArray = Split(text, " ")
    For i = LBound(textArray) To UBound(textArray)
        For j = i + 1 To UBound(textArray)
            If textArray(i) = textArray(j) Then
                DuplicateWordCheck = True
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Function
```

So if your examples start in cell A1, in cell B1 put the formula `=DuplicateWordCheck(A1)`

Comment: I'm sorry, I've never used VBA